# Hosting Account suspended repeatedly

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, web-services

I have a linux hosting account with hostmetro.com with about 10 domains on it. Recently I have been facing a serious downtime problem. Every few days they suspend my account by informing me that they got a spam complaint against my account. They provide the content of the complaint which is something like this:

https://www.pastebucket.com/558849

The hosting company is no help at all they just tell me to update my wordpress/plugin installations and they are all updated but i am still getting these complaints and suspensions like one a week.

If anyone who faced an issue like this, or knows any information that might help me, please help.

Thank You

Edit: All domains on my account are running wordpress installations.

Comment: Your account is sending out spam emails. How that is occurring is up to you to figure out. You probably have insecure code somewhere on your website that is being exploited. Your host is definitely not responsible for helping you find it.

Comment: I'm still a novice developer. I have been trying to find the insecure code but it has been to no avail. Can you tell me where I could find help on this issue?

Comment: You might have malicious code in your installation. Check this if it helps http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-plugins-detect-malicious-codes/

Answer (score 1):

> ...they just tell me to update my wordpress/plugin installations and they are all updated but i am still getting these complaints...

Take the company's advice at least to some degree. They're telling you that what you have installed is causing users (regardless of their interest in your site) to receive a bad experience as a result of something running on your site.

As people have mentioned, it stems from a script which contains hidden malicious code that causes harm or inconvenience, whether it be to the website itself, or to the server resources, and its very likely that such malicious code contains a script that sends email to a random user in a database (almost?) every time someone requests a page.

I know I'm overly detailed there, but the point is, at least one script you have installed is causing harm to your server.

I suggest removing the scripts you no longer need, and securing your system with better passwords so random guests can't get into FTP or the like. Also, ask the company to scan the computer with your web pages on it for any viruses and have them removed.

I would also suggest running any new scripts on a local server first before uploading them to the online server. This means download apache, php, mysql and wordpress and run them all. That way, if they decide to become malicious, you'll be the only one affected, not everyone in the world.

Comment: Thank You for your advice. I read a lot about this issue and found that usually free wordpress themes are likely to have such malicious scripts. therefore, I already took down one of my websites which was recently reported. I will also change the passwords as you suggested, today.

Comment: I also changed the file permissions of the mail folder in my file manager to 100. Usually its supposed to be 751. 751 gives the World mode execute permission, Group mode read and execute permission and user mode read, write and execute permission. What I changed it to, 100 gives only the User, only the Execute permission. This is allowing me to recieve and send emails as well. 

Do you think this step should disable the script to send the email everytime the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As per many hosting companies terms of service. E-Mail spam is the worst, if a IP Address is blacklisted then all Shared Customers are infected. If you are gaining this problem and continue to get this problem, I would suggest moving to a VPS or Dedicated Server. This will allow you to have your own IP Address and should stop the Hosting Company from Suspending you for a SPAM Complaint.

Comment: Maybe so but moving the site en-bloc to a new host may simply move the infected script.  You would then still get spam complaints.